# PIL image show() doesn't work on windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, python-imaging-library, show

I would like to show an image using python on windows and other platforms.
When I do:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('image.png')
im.show()
```

my default viewer opens up and tells me that `Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because either this file was deleted` , etc.

The file is probably deleted because PIL calls the os with the following command: `"start /wait %s && del /f %s" % (file, file)`

I found a workaround [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t707158-python-pil-and-vista-windows-7-show-not-working.html). They recommend changing PIL's code to `"start /wait %s && PING 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > NUL && del /f %s" % (file, file)`. 
However, I want others to be able to use my code.

Is there a simple solution? Should I look for an alternative to PIL that would work crossplatform?

Comment: Ok, found a solution [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/308081):

    `import webbrowser`
    `webbrowser.open('image.png')`

It opens the default viewer, not the browser, on my machine.

Comment: please post that as an answer (and accept it), so others that come here this question can find it easily.

Comment: @Petr Viktorin. This requires 100 reputation, or I have to wait 8 hours...

Comment: Well, you do have 100 reputation ;)

Comment: Microsoft broke the "start" command. It always WANTED you to specify a window title first.  `start /wait "Title"  %s ....` is the correct Windows syntax. THe latest GitHub Pillow code contains this fix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, found a solution [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/308081):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('image.png')
```

It opens the default viewer, not the browser, on my machine.

Also, there is `os.startfile`.

Comment: how does that help display the (possibly modified)  `im` object/image as was previously possible with `im.show()`? What if I want to display `im`. I guess you can save it to some temporary filename and then use that ..

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be opened by MS paint only, you can use:

`start /wait mspaint %s && del /f %s" % (file, file)`

The `/wait` is not having any effect when the file name is specified directly.

Comment: If you want to make the above change, then edit:
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageShow.py

around line 99, replace 
'return "start /wait %s && del /f %s" % (file, file)'
with
'return "start /wait mspaint %s && del /f %s" % (file, file)'

thanks @NikhilGeorge for the mspaint suggestion!

Comment: Or  just fix the real problem. Add "WindowTitle" to "start" command as the first parameter. Be sure to INCLUDE the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

When Photo Viewer does appear, 
Go to menu on top ->Open->Choice Program-> Select Paint 
On Spanish -> Abrir-> Elegir Programa -> seleccionar Paint

image reference: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HN6A.png)