# There is no such file when picture opened with Image.show()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
import tkMessageBox
from PIL import Image

    elif UserHand == "Scissors":
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Your choice","You chose: Scissors")
            im = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Jeroen\\Downloads\\Scissors.jpg')
            im.show()
```

So. What I am trying to do is when a choice is made that it opens the picture, however the screen does open but it says that the file does not exists.

I checked it and when I go to the file path the picture is there.
I hope you can help me

I can't post pictures but here are the pictures i wanted to add in:

http://gyazo.com/ce8ceca3128cdd2c95fbb6d77becf710

http://gyazo.com/bb148fd44d3e8117054e635b67635a80

Thanks, Jeroen

Comment: Do you have administrative access on your computer? IIRC, PIL will create a temporary file somewhere that is effectively a copy of the loaded image. If your account has restricted rights, maybe your OS will prevent you from creating that temporary file, and then the picture viewer will have nothing to load.

Comment: Yes I do have administrator rights on my account.

Comment: Also I am using Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: I think it deletes instantly or does not even create the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have been looking for a few hours last night and I found it was an error in ImageShow.py

I fixed it using this post: [PIL image show() doesn't work on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715501/pil-image-show-doesnt-work-on-windows-7)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932976/python-imaging-library-show-on-windows

Comment: Thank you @MarkRansom!

I am now using this with Tkinter but when I use my image with ImageTk.PhotoImage("example.jpg"), I get this error: TclError: image "<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=300x200 at 0x293EB98>" doesn't exist. I thought maybe you can help me with it since I can't post another question cause of my low reputation.

Comment: That looks like you're passing an image to a function that requires a filename as a string.

Comment: How would I make it that it reads it as an image, because I am giving the path to it as you can see here: http://gyazo.com/b85e4c062d382d5a6443df38dc7efabd

Comment: You definitely need to ask a new question. The documentation I find says you can do it exactly the way your code shows.

Comment: I can't make a new question at the moment, so I will sit it out and keep trying and searching on how to fix it, I hope it is not something in PIL or Tkinter again.

Comment: I also checked this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718663/tkinter-image-not-showing-or-giving-an-error about .gif